# Generate summary data based on configuration table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, summary

I'm trying to generate a summary from a list of scores in SQL Server 2008.
I have two tables: [**SQL Fiddle link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85314)

The `ScorePerson` table contains people's ID and their score from -5 to 15.  End users of my SQL/Stored Procedure needs to create a summary like this:

```
Scoreband| TotalNoOfPeople | AvgScore
--------------------------------
-5 to 0  | 2               | -2
0 to 5   | 3               |  2
5 to 10  | 2               |  8
10 to 15 | 3               | 13.3
```

The score band i.e. the min and max values should be configurable from the `ScoreMinMax` table by the end user.

I have tried to achive this using CASE stement, but it generates the summary as columns.  I I would probably need to pivot it or use UNION from multiple select statements.  But this approach doesn't seem scalable if there were new rows added to the `ScoreMinMax` table.
So far I was able to achieve some results similar to the example above using CROSS JOINT, but it doesn't always produces the correct results.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction on how to achieve this please?

[**SQL Fiddle link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85314)

```
ScorePerson - contains actual scores
```

[image: Table screenshot]

```
ScoreMinMax - the configuration for min and max score bands
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want a query that will generate the selects a resultset that look like the table `ScoreMinMax` from the `ScorePerson` alone?

Comment: how do you handle the overlap values 0,5,10... ?

Comment: You can either have the Min and Max scores like -5 to 0, 1 to 5, 6 to 10 and so on, or do what podiluska has suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions:

```
select title ScoreBand,
  count(*) TotalNoPeople, 
  avg(p.score) AvgScore  
from scoreperson p
inner join scoreminmax m
  on p.score between m.minscore and m.maxscore
group by Title
order by cast(left(title, 2) as int)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85314/19)

If you have no person in an existing range, you can us something like this:

```
select case when title is not null 
            then title
            else 'No Range' end ScoreBand,
  count(personid) TotalNoPeople, 
  avg(p.score) AvgScore  
from scoreperson p
left join scoreminmax m
  on p.score between m.minscore and m.maxscore
group by id, Title
order by id
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b87b8/4)

edit #2, based on your comments you can use:

```
select m.title ScoreBand,
  count(p.personid) TotalNoPeople, 
  avg(p.score) AvgScore  
from scoreminmax m
left join scoreperson p
  on p.score between m.minscore and m.maxscore
group by m.id, m.Title
order by m.id;
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14b64/14)

Comment: Great, thanks.  In case no one falls within a given score band.  Is it possible to still output that band with 0 TotalNoPeople, rather than not showing that at all?

Comment: @Sivakanesh See my answer below that will do that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, if say the ScoreBand '-5 to 0' does not have any one in it.  Rather than not displaying the band, I would like to say -count for '5 to 0' is 0. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b775/6

Comment: @Sivakanesh ok, but do you want to display anything if there is a score outside of the ranges in the table?

Comment: No that is not required in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select Title, count(personid), AVG(score)
from 
    scoreminmax  
    left join scoreperson 
    on scoreperson.score>=minscore 
    and scoreperson.score<maxscore 
group by ID,title 
order by ID
```

Note that I have included scores on the boundaries (0,5,10) in only one of the groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
select smm.Title Scoreband, count(*) TotalNoOfPeople, avg(sp.Score) AvgScore
from 
    ScorePerson sp
    inner join
    ScoreMinMax smm on sp.Score >= smm.MinScore and sp.Score < smm.MaxScore
group by smm.Title
```